# fabricjs subclassing objects are not grouped

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

please see below link.

please run the sample code.

## 1 rectangle - grouped. success.

1. click addRect twice. (show two rectangle)
2. drag and selection two objects.
3. click group button.
4. success group objects.

## 2 subclassing object - fail.

1. click addLabeledRect twice (show two subclassing objects) - just rectangle with text
2. drag and selection two objects.
3. click group button.
4. failed and error message on console.

subclassing objects are not transform to group object?

I tested group object with subclassing object and rectangle.
when rectangles are grouped well, but subclassing objects are not.

I uses v1.4.4

error messages are below.

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function fabric-1.3.7.js:10702
    fabric.Object.fabric.util.createClass.renderfabric-1.3.7.js:10702
    fabric.Group.fabric.util.createClass._renderObjectfabric-1.3.7.js:15504
    fabric.Group.fabric.util.createClass.renderfabric-1.3.7.js:15477
    fabric.StaticCanvas.fabric.util.createClass._drawfabric-1.3.7.js:5751
    fabric.StaticCanvas.fabric.util.createClass._renderObjectsfabric-1.3.7.js:5879
    fabric.StaticCanvas.fabric.util.createClass.renderAllfabric-1.3.7.js:5850
    fabric.Collection.addfabric-1.3.7.js:181
    (anonymous function)GroupSubclassing.html:71
    x.event.dispatchjquery-2.0.3.js:4676
    y.handle
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Tfb2d/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem with the cloned object missing subclass members.

For a simple workaround, add this:

```
LabeledRectangle.fromObject = function (object) {
    return new LabeledRectangle(object);
};
```

after defining your object.